# Importing multiple text files to Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have about 600 text files. Each file contains 2 columns and is `space delimited`. Is there any way I can import all of them to the same excel spreadsheet?

I saw a post about this and used the following script but that didn't work for me. It gived me `User-defined type not defined`

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim folder As folder
Dim file As file
Dim FileText As TextStream
Dim TextLine As String
Dim Items() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim cl As Range

' Get a FileSystem object
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

' get the directory you want
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("D:\mypath\")

' set the starting point to write the data to
Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)

' Loop thru all files in the folder
For Each file In folder.Files
    ' Open the file
    Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

    ' Read the file one line at a time
    Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
        TextLine = FileText.ReadLine

        ' Parse the line into | delimited pieces
        Items = Split(TextLine, "|")

        ' Put data on one row in active sheet
        For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
            cl.Offset(0, i).Value = Items(i)
        Next

        ' Move to next row
        Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    ' Clean up
    FileText.Close
Next file

Set FileText = Nothing
Set file = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Either add the `Windows Scripting Runtime` Reference mentioned below, or change these 2 lines: `Dim fso As FileSystemObject` and `Dim FileText As TextStream` to `... As Object`, and then `Set fso = New FileSystemObject` to `Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`. Also make the changes mentioned by @mkingston below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you need to set a reference to the Windows Scripting Host Object Model.

To do this, from the Visual Basic Editor choose Tools/References, then scroll down to find "Windows Script Host Object Model". Tick this box then press OK. Now try to run your code again.

Additionally, I notice you mention that your data is split into two columns and space-delimited. You'll need to replace the delimiter on the following line:

```
Items = Split(TextLine, "|")
```

With this:

```
Items = Split(TextLine, " ")
```

Finally, you'd be slightly better off replacing this:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
  cl.Offset(0, i).Value = Items(i)
Next
```

With this:

```
cl.Resize(1,UBound(Items)-LBound(Items)+1).value = Items
```

Comment: And how should I do that?(I have no knowledge about visual basic)

Comment: When I select Tools -> References. This option is not accessible for me. I mean its not highlighted/non-clickable <insert correct term here>. I pasted the code by choosing the `add new module` option after pressing `Alt+F11` in the worksheet. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you mean the references button is non-clickable? If that's the case you need to choose Run/Reset, then try again.

Comment: It does seem to copy some data but it is incorrect. My second column in all the files is not being copied.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, you don't need the application.transpose, if you've made that change. Edited accordingly.

Comment: FileSystemObject requires the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` reference, not the `Windows Script Host Object Model`.